# The value of K in KNN & the accuracy of the model

Tags: knn

I am working on KNN algorithm, I have some questions please I need answers:

1. I tried different values of K such as 3, 5, 7, and sqrt(n)=73. I get different accuracies according to these different values of K. What K should I use in my model and why ??
2. What is the best percentage that I should use to split the dataset into train and test sets ??
3. why the accuracy of the train set is always greater than the accuracy of test set ??
4. Which accuracy (train accuracy or test accuracy) is used to describe the overall model accuracy  ??

Answer (score 0):

1. Choosing the value of ***K*** is not a exact science. In [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/215065) post, *user20160* explained a procedure to choose a good ***K*** using [*k-fold cross validation*](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/k-fold-cross-validation-6b8518070833).
2. Usually, 80/20 and 70/30 ratios are used but once again, it is not a absolute truth. If your train set ratio is too large, your model could overfit which means your model learns specially for the train set and will not be performant with real cases. On another hand, if your train set is too small, your model could underfit.
3. The accuracy of the train set is often greater than the test one because your model is only trained with the train set and test dataset are cases your model has never seen before. It is like learning to ride a bike with only one bike and being evaluated with another bike.
4. The train accuracy is not realistic to evaluate the performance of your model since train dataset is well known by your model. Test accuracy is more relevant because test dataset is new and has never been seen by your model.

To better understand everything about model evaluation I strongly recommend you to take look at the cross validation link above.